# passing array from input to php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, html, mysqli

```
<select name="mul_cat1[]" class="form-text"  style="width: 85%;" >
<option value="">-Select-</option>
<option value="1">Pianoforte</option>
<option value="2">All Wind</option>
</select>


<select name="mul_cat1[]" class="form-text"  style="width: 85%;" >
<option value="">-Select-</option>
<option value="1">Pianoforte</option>
<option value="2">All Wind</option>
</select>

<input  name="entrytitle1[]" type="text"  required />
<input  name="entrytitle1[]" type="text"  required />

<input  name="composer1[]" type="text"  required/>
```

end of the first entry

start of the second entry

```
<select name="mul_cat1[]" class="form-text"  style="width: 85%;" >
<option value="">-Select-</option>
<option value="1">Pianoforte</option>
<option value="2">All Wind</option>
</select>


<select name="mul_cat1[]" class="form-text"  style="width: 85%;" >
<option value="">-Select-</option>
<option value="1">Pianoforte</option>
<option value="2">All Wind</option>
</select>

<input  name="entrytitle1[]" type="text"  required />
<input  name="entrytitle1[]" type="text"  required />

<input  name="composer1[]" type="text"  required/>
```

what i want to do now is know how i can capture the data and push it to the mysql database. so mul_cat1 must be pushed into the table in different rows and entrytitle must correspond respectfully with the mulcat.

so the output in the Mysql database will look like this:

```
id | mul_cat1 | entrytitle1 | composer1
 1 | 1 | milk | John
 2 | 2 | water | John
 3 | 2 | dance | Mark
 4 | 1 | sing | Mark
```

this is what i am using but it isn't working

```
$data2=array();
for($x=0,$l=count($entrytitle1); $x<$l; $x++){

    $muldata=implode(',', $mul_cat1);

    echo $muldata;
    $myArray2 = explode(',', $entrytitle1[$x]);// you can use your own filter for names 
    $myArray3 = explode(',', $muldata[$x]);// you can use your own filter for names          
    foreach (array_combine($myArray2, $myArray3) as $title => $mul) {
        $data2[]='("'.trim($title).'", "'.trim($mul).'", "'.$_SESSION['id'].'", 2, "'.$entry_id.'")';
    }
}

$query="INSERT INTO multiple_category (title_of_entry, multiple_cat,con_registration_idcon_registration, acts_idacts, entry_id) VALUES".implode(',',$data2);

$result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
```

Comment: Use a `for()` loop to iterate through all the `$_POST` arrays.

Comment: i am going to update my code to show waht i have done i tired the for loop and its not working

Comment: still here waiting for help

Comment: `$muldata` is not an array, so using `$muldata[$x]` makes little sense. You should be using `$mul_cat[$x]` to get the corresponding input.

Comment: I don't quite understand your form. Why do you have two `mul_cat1` menus, two `entrytitle1` text fields, but only one `composer1` field in each entry? How do these fields relate to each other in the database?

Comment: And why do you do `explode(',', $entrytitle1[$x])`? Does the user enter a comma-separated list in the text field?

Comment: yes they enter a comma separted list in the input field. But i have abandoned the above code.